# If a list of tasks has to be executed over several calls, how does one ensure that each task is executed once?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, scheduled-tasks

We have a scheduler that allots a service a time slice of about 30 seconds every so often. That service must execute a list of tasks, but it takes more than 30 seconds to execute all the tasks. Therefore it has to do those tasks over multiple calls.

Under these circumstances, how does one ensure that every task is executed, and no task is executed more than once? (The list of tasks can change between calls, they're not all distinct and the list of tasks itself cannot be modified by the service, each task, even those distinct have to be executed, you can save to disk, so you can persist a list of tasks, and a task is done if it's deleted by the user.)

Comment: What ideas have you tried so far?

Comment: In what way does the list of tasks change between calls? If the tasks are "not all distinct", do you want multiple identical tasks to each be executed once, or only one of them to be executed? Since the service cannot modify the list, how about a copy of the list?

Comment: The scheduler calls the service every 10 minutes or so. More than enough time for a user to edit the list of tasks.

Comment: From what I can understand, if, in the list, some task remains untouched between calls and the service completes it, then the service should not start that task again in a future call. What happens if the service completes a task that gets deleted afterwards? This whole system you have going on seems very arbitrary to me, especially regarding your statement that the list of tasks cannot be modified by the service.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty damn arbitrary, but I got the job, and I have to do it.

Comment: Make a copy of the list at the start and use that for the duration?

Comment: You need to start with defining the requirements. Maybe you've done that already, but you certainly haven't provided complete requirements in your question. You're unlikely to get a satisfactory answer if you don't give us more information. For example, edit your question and answer add responses to the issues posed by Nelfeal.

Comment: I'm not allowed to do that, Dukeling. Just asked :-(

Comment: You might want to provide an actual example of what the list looks like, examples of modifications to the list and then an example of what you want the service to do at each step, together with an explanation of why it does that. Although I can't see any other answer than to save some combination of tasks that still need to be done and those that've already been done.